# Where do I get the correct gdi+ c++ wrappers from for VS21015?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, gdi+

I've got windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusheaders.h & etc. - but we're upgrading from VS2013 to VS2015 and I'm getting endless compiler errors, such as:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusheaders.h(695): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusheaders.h(695): warning C4458: declaration of 'nativeCap' hides class member
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusheaders.h(695): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusheaders.h(710): note: see declaration of 'Gdiplus::CustomLineCap::nativeCap'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusimageattributes.h(364): warning C4458: declaration of 'nativeImageAttr' hides class member
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusimageattributes.h(364): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusimageattributes.h(378): note: see declaration of 'Gdiplus::ImageAttributes::nativeImageAttr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusmatrix.h(296): warning C4458: declaration of 'nativeMatrix' hides class member
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusmatrix.h(296): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\gdiplusmatrix.h(310): note: see declaration of 'Gdiplus::Matrix::nativeMatrix'
```

Now, it seems I could use the /Wv flag as indicated - but my guess is I need an updated version of the Windows SDK which contains the current version of the GDI+ C++ wrappers.

However, I am finding no such results viz Google.

UPDATE:
I'm finding only more and more of this type of mess.
I cleaned up the warnings from Gdiplus.h by ensuring that I #prama warning(disable:4458) before #include'ing gdiplus.h, but I'm getting:

```
1>c:\users\steve\vault\cimex cad-cam\17.0\mfc toolbox\cstring utilities.h(441): warning C4459: declaration of 'chQuote' hides global declaration
1>  c:\users\steve\vault\cimex cad-cam\17.0\mfc toolbox\cstring utilities.h(441): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
```

From my own code where VS2015 is considering that free function argument to be in conflict with c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\statreg.h - which defines a global in the namespace ATL!

What a mess!  Is this really as the standards body wanted?!  This is nuts!  Now every variable or argument everywhere has to avoid name conflict with totally unrelated junk from other parts of windows or MFC/ATL because maybe something somewhere might be hiding a global... dude!  This is DUMB. :(

Comment: I see that there are other windows kits under Program files (x86) - but not clear on how to choose one that compiles correctly...?

Comment: [How to: Use the Windows 10 SDK in a Windows Desktop Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186161.aspx). That should do it, if indeed it is a matter of using an updated SDK.

Comment: Damn - I assumed it was something like that too - and found that interface - but my only option is "8.1" even though I see the other SDKs under Program Files (x86). :(

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2015 installed, it should have come with the Windows 10 SDK. I don't know whether you have to select specific features in the installer, to have it install the GDI+ headers as well (although I believe the SDK is an all-or-nothing deal). But if it doesn't show up in the IDE's interface, something may have gone wrong. The installers aren't exactly known for being the most robust in the universe.

Comment: I've got a screamin' headache so far.  Which is about par for the course everytime I have to upgrade to Window's newest compiler.  Endless errors that make no sense.  I tried updating Windows SDK 8.1 - made no difference.  I already updated VS2015 to update 3.  No difference.  I fixed all my code's issues - but because I'm using "treat warnings as errors" the long list of GDI+ header errors (and SDK header errors) makes it fail to compile...  I am currently at a loss as to why VS2015 would ship with SDK headers that are full of warnings?

Comment: They usually work out of the box, unless you enable the [/Za (Disable Language Extensions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) compiler option.

Comment: definitely not disabling language extensions.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1044210

Comment: Meanwhile, use Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Warning level = Level3

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure what the bug report actually means?  I'm guessing that the warning shouldn't fire when one explicitly dereferences a member with the same name as a function argument?  Either way, I think MS should supply headers that either explicitly turn off such warnings (if they're certain there's no issue, and the warnings are spurious), or they should fix their code so it doesn't issue a warning in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the SDKs as shipped are indeed full of warnings at /W4.
Either one must drop back to /W3 or override the various warnings before calling various SDK headers.

Just FYI - VS2013 was able to compile those same SDKs with /W4.  So presumably there are more warnings, or they catch more violations.

Comment: It helps if you want to downvote this to specify why?  If you have a better answer - FEEL FREE TO ADD IT, hmmm?

Comment: I don't know why either; I can confirm this is what happens with virtually all the Windows API headers, even with VS2013. I thought it has to do with combining /W4 with /Tc, but this question proves otherwise... And I'm pretty sure similar questions have been asked here before.